# mu4e and multiple accounts/context don't work

Tags: mu4e

Hi I have three gmail adresses, I can choose the contexts but it still shows the inbox of `account1`. `offlineimap` is configured with `localfolders` equals `~/.Mail/accountX@gmail.com`

Here is part of my config:

```
(setq mu4e-maildir "~/.Mail")
(setq mu4e-contexts
  `( ,(make-mu4e-context
        :name "account1"
        :enter-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Entering account1 context"))
        :leave-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Leaving account1 context"))
        :vars '( ( user-mail-address      . "account1@gmail.com"  )
                 ( user-full-name         . "Peter Pan" )
                 ))

     ,(make-mu4e-context
        :name "account2"
        :enter-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Entering account2 context"))
        :leave-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Leaving account2 context"))
        :vars '( ( user-mail-address       . "account2")
                 ( user-full-name          . "Peter Pan" )
                 ))
     ,(make-mu4e-context
        :name "account3"
        :enter-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Entering account3 context"))
        :leave-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Leaving account3 context"))
        :vars '( ( user-mail-address       . "account3")
                 ( user-full-name          . "Hanno Jung" )
                 ))
))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `:match-func` in your contexts, contexts are entered using that function